# Using Boost asio to receive commands and execute them

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, istream, streambuf

I'm trying to make a boost server, which will receive commands and do certain things. Now I would like to create a function, that will receive a file and save it to a specific location. The problem is with serialization. I don't know how can I recognize a command in a stream in an efficint way. I tried with boost::asio::read_until. And actually my code works. First file is being sent and received perfectly. But I am getting an error (The file handle supplied is not valid) when client sends second file. I would be very grateful for every advice. Thanks in an advance!

```
    bool Sync::start_server() {



    boost::asio::streambuf request_buf; 
    std::istream request_stream(&request_buf);
    boost::system::error_code error; 


    try {

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), conf->def_port));
        acceptor.accept(socket); //socket is a member of class Sync
        while (true)
        {

            error.clear();


            size_t siz = boost::asio::read_until(socket, request_buf, "\n\n");

            std::cout << "request size:" << request_buf.size() << "\n";

            string command;
            string parameter;
            size_t data_size = 0;

            request_stream >> command;
            request_stream >> parameter;
            request_stream >> data_size;


            request_buf.consume(siz);//And also this

            //cut filename from path below
            size_t pos = parameter.find_last_of('\\');
            if (pos != std::string::npos)
                parameter = parameter.substr(pos + 1);
            //cut filename from path above
            //command = "save";// constant until I make up other functions
             //execute(command, parameter, data_size);

            save(parameter,data_size);//parameter is filename

        }

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And function to save file to a hard drive:

```
bool Sync::save(string filename, size_t filesize) {
    boost::array<char, 1024> buf;
    cout << "filesize is" << filesize;
    size_t data_size = 0;
    boost::system::error_code error;
    std::ofstream output_file(filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);
    if (!output_file)
    {
        std::cout << "failed to open " << filename << std::endl;
        return __LINE__;
    }
    while (true) {



        size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

        if (len>0)
            output_file.write(buf.c_array(), (std::streamsize)len);
        if (output_file.tellp() == (std::fstream::pos_type)(std::streamsize)filesize)
        {

            output_file.close();
            buf.empty();
            break; // file was received
        }


        if (error)
        {
            socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, error);
            socket.close(error);
            output_file.close();
            buf.empty();
            break;//an error occured
        }



    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `read_until` might read beyond the delimiter (therefore `request_buf.size()` can be more than `siz`). This is a conceptual problem when you implement `save` because you read `data_size` bytes from the socket, which ignores any data already in `request_buf`
2. These things are code smells:

   ```
   if (output_file.tellp() == (std::fstream::pos_type)(std::streamsize)filesize) {
   ```

   (***never*** use C-style casts). And

   ```
   return __LINE__; // huh? just `true` then
   ```

   And

   ```
       buf.empty();
   ```

   (That has no effect whatsoever).

I present here three versions:

- First Cleanup
- Simplify (using `tcp::iostream`)
- Simplify! (assuming more things about the request format)

### First Cleanup

Here's a reasonable cleanup:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3deeb76b4257ee69)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::tcp;

struct Conf {
    int def_port = 6767;
} s_config;

struct Request {
    std::string command;
    std::string parameter;
    std::size_t data_size = 0;

    std::string get_filename() const {
        // cut filename from path - TODO use boost::filesystem::path instead
        return parameter.substr(parameter.find_last_of('\\') + 1);
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Request& req) {
        return is >> req.command >> req.parameter >> req.data_size;
    }
};

struct Sync {
    bool start_server();
    bool save(Request const& req, boost::asio::streambuf& request_buf);

    ba::io_service& io_service;
    tcp::socket socket{ io_service };
    Conf const *conf = &s_config;
};

bool Sync::start_server() {

    boost::asio::streambuf request_buf;
    boost::system::error_code error;

    try {

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), conf->def_port));
        acceptor.accept(socket); // socket is a member of class Sync
        while (true) {

            error.clear();

            std::string req_txt;

            {
                char const* delim = "\n\n";
                size_t siz = boost::asio::read_until(socket, request_buf, delim, error);

                // correct for actual request siz
                auto b = buffers_begin(request_buf.data()), 
                     e = buffers_end(request_buf.data());

                auto where = std::search(b, e, delim, delim+strlen(delim));
                siz = where==e
                    ? std::distance(b,e)
                    : std::distance(b,where)+strlen(delim);

                std::copy_n(b, siz, back_inserter(req_txt));
                request_buf.consume(siz); // consume only the request text bits from the buffer
            }

            std::cout << "request size:" << req_txt.size() << "\n";
            std::cout << "Request text: '" << req_txt << "'\n";
            Request req;

            {
                std::istringstream request_stream(req_txt);
                request_stream.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
                request_stream >> req;
            }

            save(req, request_buf); // parameter is filename
        }

    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Error parsing request: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return false;
}

bool Sync::save(Request const& req, boost::asio::streambuf& request_buf) {
    auto filesize = req.data_size;
    std::cout << "filesize is: " << filesize << "\n";

    {
        std::ofstream output_file(req.get_filename(), std::ios::binary);
        if (!output_file) {
            std::cout << "failed to open " << req.get_filename() << std::endl;
            return true;
        }

        // deplete request_buf
        if (request_buf.size()) {
            if (request_buf.size() < filesize)
            {
                filesize -= request_buf.size();
                output_file << &request_buf;
            }
            else {
                // copy only filesize already available bytes
                std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&request_buf), filesize, 
                        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(output_file));
                filesize = 0;
            }
        }

        while (filesize) {
            boost::array<char, 1024> buf;
            boost::system::error_code error;

            std::streamsize len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

            if (len > 0)
            {
                output_file.write(buf.c_array(), len);
                filesize -= len;
            }

            if (error) {
                socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, error); // ignore error
                socket.close(error);
                break; // an error occured
            }
        }
    } // closes output_file

    return false;
}

int main() {
    ba::io_service svc;

    Sync s{svc};
    s.start_server();

    svc.run();
}
```

Prints with a client like `echo -ne "save test.txt 12\n\nHello world\n" | netcat 127.0.0.1 6767`:

```
request size:18
Request text: 'save test.txt 12

'
filesize is: 12
request size:1
Request text: '
'
Error parsing request: basic_ios::clear: iostream error
```

### SIMPLIFY

However, since everything is synchronous, why not just use `tcp::iostream socket;`. That would make `start_server` look like this:

```
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), conf->def_port));
acceptor.accept(*socket.rdbuf());

while (socket) {
    std::string req_txt, line;

    while (getline(socket, line) && !line.empty()) {
        req_txt += line + "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "request size:" << req_txt.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Request text: '" << req_txt << "'\n";

    Request req;
    if (std::istringstream(req_txt) >> req)
        save(req);
}
```

And `save` even simpler:

```
void Sync::save(Request const& req) {
    char buf[1024];
    size_t remain = req.data_size, n = 0;

    for (std::ofstream of(req.get_filename(), std::ios::binary);
        socket.read(buf, std::min(sizeof(buf), remain)), (n = socket.gcount());
        remain -= n)
    {
        if (!of.write(buf, n))
            break;
    }
}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0987b1e8ddfb348)</kbd>**

When tested with

```
for f in test{a..z}.txt; do (echo -ne "save $f 12\n\nHello world\n"); done | netcat 127.0.0.1 6767
```

that prints:

```
request size:18
Request text: 'save testa.txt 12
'
request size:18
Request text: 'save testb.txt 12
'
[... snip ...]
request size:18
Request text: 'save testz.txt 12
'
request size:0
Request text: ''
```

### Even Simpler

If you know that the request is a single line, or whitespace is not significant:

```
struct Sync {
    void run_server();
    void save(Request const& req);

  private:
    Conf const *conf = &s_config;
    tcp::iostream socket;
};

void Sync::run_server() {
    ba::io_service io_service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), conf->def_port));
    acceptor.accept(*socket.rdbuf());

    for (Request req; socket >> std::noskipws >> req; std::cout << req << " handled\n")
        save(req);
}

void Sync::save(Request const& req) {
    char buf[1024];
    size_t remain = req.data_size, n = 0;

    for (std::ofstream of(req.get_filename(), std::ios::binary);
        socket.read(buf, std::min(sizeof(buf), remain)), (n = socket.gcount());
        remain -= n) 
    {
        if (!of.write(buf, n)) break;
    }
}

int main() {
    Sync().run_server();
}
```

That's the entire program in ~33 lines of code. See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c732f58016e1cc2)</kbd>**, printing:

```
Request {"save" "testa.txt"} handled
Request {"save" "testb.txt"} handled
Request {"save" "testc.txt"} handled
[... snip ...]
Request {"save" "testy.txt"} handled
Request {"save" "testz.txt"} handled
```

Comment: Thank You. Your code is working almost perfectly. I've got a little problem when I try to send a file that name contains a whitespace.

Comment: @tangor obviously. Your chosen protocol is simply inadequate for that. You'll need to decide on what way you're going to delimit the fields in your request. You didn't, so I assumed it was the delimiter that you actually used in your own code. If that's not sufficient, perhaps change all of the 1 line of code that defines this behaviour: [see line 22](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dda75ed1aff8b32)

Comment: In other words, without requirements, you never know when you're done. Or better yet: without requirements, my code was working perfectly. You're actually running into the problem known as [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Learning to see the real task and the essential requirements early will avoid a lot of frustration.

Comment: Is there a way to put server_run() in a thread(make it listening at all time) and send command to a client from a server (using tcp::iostream socket) at a certain time?